# How to get navigation back button title?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem!.title` causes **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** while clearly there is a back button with title string in it in my view controller

How do I get the back button's title string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` you should be aware that this is the bar button item that will be used in the navigation bar when `self` is not the `topViewController` but rather immediately below the `topViewController`. That is `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is not the button currently visible when `self` is the `topViewController` but when another view controller is pushed on top of it.

You should also be aware:

> When this property is nil, the navigation item uses the value in its title property to create an appropriate back button.

Meaning that `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` can be `nil` and still have a title. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624958-backbarbuttonitem)

If you want to know what text is being used with the back button You could could say something like:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    var backButtonText: String? {
        guard let self.viewControllers.count > 1 else { return nil }
        let viewController = self.viewControllers[self.viewControllers.count - 2]
        return viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title ?? viewController.title
    }
}
```

Which could be called like:

```
print(self.navigationController?.backButtonText ?? "No back button title")
```

Comment: is it also possible now to access back button custom view for top controller ?

Comment: What if I only want to change back button text in one view controller?